# EF core + Automapper ID-only related entity collection, how?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, iqueryable, anonymous-types

I have a simple problem - I would like one of the RESTful endpoints serve a resource DTO (auto-mapped) with its related resources as their IDs only. However there does not seem to be any way to implement it without loading the whole(and heavy) related entities. Consider following (DB first) example model:

```
public partial class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Post // some heavy entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

and its corresponding DTO

```
// api/v1/blogs serves collection of following type
public class BlogSlimDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int[] PostIds { get; set; }
}
```

a straightforward soltion would be to fetch all the related `Post`s from database and discard all data except for the IDs, but that can be inefficient or even unfeasible depending on related `Post` entity size:

```
var result = ctx.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts) //fecth everything and discard it on next line
    .Select(blog => _mapper.Map<BlogSlimDto>(blog)); 
    // simply use a profile that discards Posts but keeps their Ids, e.g.
    // .forMember(dto => dto.PostIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(db.Posts.Select(p => p.Id)))
```

there is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760904/including-only-id-of-related-entity-in-entity-framework-core) which offers a solution using anonymous types, however this does not play well with Automapper at all:

```
var result = ctx.Blogs.Select(blog => new {
   blog.Id,
   blog.Url,
   PostIds = blog.Posts.Select(b => b.Id),
}).Select(ablog => _mapper.Map<BlogSlimDto>(ablog)); //throws, no mapping and such mapping cannot be defined
```

The code above will throw during runtime because there no Automapper mapping defined. Even worse, it cannnot be defined because there is [no support for anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639451/how-to-map-an-anonymous-object-to-a-class-by-automapper) in Automapper. Moreover, solutions with one-by-one 'manual' property assignment tend to be difficult to maintain.
Is there an alternative solution that would allow EF query without fetching whole related entities while allowing the result to be auto-mapped to the `BlogSlimDto`?

Comment: Why do you insist on using automapper.... there are only 3 properties?

Comment: @Milney there are only 3 properties in the code listing, it would needlessly bloat the post to include them all - you just have to trust the inline comments there are enough of them to justify the work (current 30s+ response time should).

Comment: I understand that you do not want to query all the properties of the libked entity, i mean just type out the select() manually instead of using automapper

Comment: @Milney reason being consistency and maintainable code/best practices - the app has around 40 endpoints so it would be confusing and error prone to use manual mapping in this one and Automapper in the rest. Fully agree that depending on scope it is sometimes not worth the effort to set the automapping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the queryable extensions:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Item, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Item.Name)));

public List<OrderLineDTO> GetLinesForOrder(int orderId)
{
  using (var context = new orderEntities())
  {
    return context.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.OrderId == orderId)
             .ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>().ToList();
  }
}
```

Replacing the Item and OrderLine with your Post and Blogs

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will look into it.